# How to delete system database in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was deleted database, using the command "Drop database msdb"

It shows `Cannot drop the database 'msdb' because it is a system database.`

i want to know how to delete system database.
Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i have more than 10 system databases that's why i want to delete that database

Comment: You can't. Also, deleting system databases is always a bad idea..

Comment: How can you have more than 10 system databases? `master`/`tempdb`/`model`/`msdb`. `distribution` possibly. What are the other 5?

Comment: your correct...martin smith

Comment: I still don't see why you are trying to delete it. Just its presence annoys you? So ignore it then. The system databases are required for the product to work.

Comment: Ok..i understand.Thank u for your valuable commands @MartinSmith.

Comment: why did this idea come in mind...

Comment: @user1254579, i am start learning c# 5 days before only,so i ask this type of question..in future i didnot post this type of question..

Comment: Its fine buddy..Keep learning..I am also a beginner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,you cannot drop system databases ..From mannual [msdb Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187112.aspx)
The msdb database is used by SQL Server Agent for scheduling alerts and jobs and by other features such as SQL Server Management Studio, Service Broker and Database Mail.
Restrictions
The following operations cannot be performed on the msdb database:

1. Changing collation. The default collation is the server collation.
2. Dropping the database.
3. Dropping the guest user from the database.
4. Enabling change data capture.
5. Participating in database mirroring.
6. Removing the primary filegroup, primary data file, or log file.
7. Renaming the database or primary filegroup.
8. Setting the database to OFFLINE.
9. Setting the primary filegroup to READ_ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

This database can't be deleted:

See restrictions:
Dropping the database.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms187112.aspx

Comment: i was created" master" (database name ) database now i cannot delete that too...the same error will display....

Comment: There is a trace flag that makes it possible to drop `msdb` IIRC but I don't see why the OP would need to. And things like SQL Agent and backup history won't work.